# Kubernetes using multiple api group in same rule. YAML

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-rbac

I have a `kind: Role` with the following rule

```
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["namespaces", "configmaps", "secrets", "pods", "replicationcontrollers", "services", "serviceaccounts"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

> This works fine just by itself, nothing wrong at all.

Now I also have another rule

```
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "daemonsets", "replicasets"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

> Perfectly fine also

My issue is if I try to merge them together like:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["namespaces", "configmaps", "secrets", "pods", "replicationcontrollers", "services", "serviceaccounts"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"] 
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "daemonsets", "replicasets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

I get an error saying `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on myproject/templates/rbac.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 27: did not find expected key`.

Am I missing a syntax error or how can you use multiple apiGroups under the same rules?

I know that I could do `- apiGroups: ["", "apps"]` but then Openshift with its infinite wisdom thinks there are namespaces under apps etc and gives a role error for the non cluster-admin user trying to get access to namespaces.apps etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone is having similar issues I had an extra space character after the `verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]-> <- there` .....